# updating data source in bootstrap typehead in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I want the drop down options to reflect all the items in an array stored in a file called companyinfo.js, which i request via ajax. I call the `dropDownList()` when the page loads.

```
function dropDownList (evt) {
    console.log("dropdownfired");
    var companyArray = [];
    $.ajax({
        url : 'assets/data/companyarray.js', //this file is just ["Facbeook", "Twitter", "Klout",]
        dataType: 'script',
        success: function(data) {
            companyArray = data;
            console.log(companyArray); //returns an array of the companies
            $('#companyInput1').attr('data-source', companyArray); //#companyInput1 is the input field where I want the typehead to be
            console.log($('#companyInput1').attr('data-source')); //returns undefined
        }
    });
}
```

UPDATES:

```
function dropDownList (evt) {
    console.log("dropdownfired");
    var companyArray = [];
    $.ajax({
        url : 'assets/data/companyarray.js', //this file is just ["Facbeook", "Twitter", "Klout",]
        dataType: 'script',
        success: function(data) {
            companyArray = data;
           console.log(companyArray); // gives array of companies
            $('#companyInput1').data('data-source', companyArray);
            console.log($('#companyInput1').data('data-source')); // gives undefined still
        }
    });
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not store anything besides strings as attributes on HTML nodes. For storing an array use the [.data()-method](http://api.jquery.com/data/) jquery offers

```
success: function(data) {
        companyArray = data;
        console.log(companyArray); //returns an array of the companies
        $('#companyInput1').data('data-source', companyArray); //#companyInput1 is the input field where I want the typehead to be
        console.log($('#companyInput1').data('data-source')); //should work
    }
```

Comment: that still isnt working for some reason. check out my updated code above